# How to add a different type of quiz for quizdown?

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte

I am trying to add one additional feature to a semi-popular JavaScript-Markdown program to create quizzes called Quizdown, that being is free response questions, in which all you would have is a single input bar to for a user to type into and will check if that string passed matches the string I specify to be the answer however I am not sure how to update the code to do so as far I have already done. I created a new type of question called 'FreeResponse' and added a class for it using the existing code that was already provided. Then in Parser I simply added it to the parseQuestion() function and am not sure where to go from here. I know that I have to update the determineQuestionType() function in order to determine if the question type is free response and that I will most likely have to update App.svelte to include a new text bar component. I will provide both files here:
quiz.ts:

```
import { writable, get, Writable } from 'svelte/store';
import autoBind from 'auto-bind';
import type { Config } from './config.js';

//Modify this file to support a FreeResponse question type

function isEqual(a1: Array<number>, a2: Array<number>): boolean {
    return JSON.stringify(a1) === JSON.stringify(a2);
}

function shuffle(array: Array<any>, n: number | undefined): Array<any> {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array
    let currentIndex = array.length,
        temporaryValue,
        randomIndex;

    // While there remain elements to shuffle...
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {
        // Pick a remaining element...
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;
        // And swap it with the current element.
        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }
    return array.slice(0, n);
}

// we need to reference the classes in the svelte app despite minifaction of class names
export type QuestionType = 'MultipleChoice' | 'SingleChoice' | 'Sequence' | 'FreeResponse';

export abstract class BaseQuestion {
    readonly text: string;
    answers: Array<Answer>;
    readonly explanation: string;
    selected: Array<number>;
    solved: boolean;
    readonly hint: string;
    readonly questionType: QuestionType;
    readonly options: Config;
    showHint: Writable<boolean>;
    visited: boolean;

    constructor(
        text: string,
        explanation: string,
        hint: string,
        answers: Array<Answer>,
        questionType: QuestionType,
        options: Config
    ) {
        if (answers.length === 0) {
            throw 'no answers for question provided';
        }
        this.text = text;
        this.explanation = explanation;
        this.hint = hint;
        this.solved = false;
        this.showHint = writable(false);
        this.options = options;
        this.answers = answers;
        this.questionType = questionType;
        this.visited = false;
        autoBind(this);
        this.reset();
    }

    enableHint() {
        this.showHint.update((val) => true);
    }

    reset() {
        this.selected = [];
        this.solved = false;
        this.visited = false;
        this.showHint.set(false);
        if (this.options.shuffleAnswers) {
            this.answers = shuffle(this.answers, this.answers.length);
        }
    }
    abstract isCorrect(): boolean;
}

class Blanks extends BaseQuestion {
    isCorrect() {
        this.solved = false;
        return this.solved;
    }
}

class Pairs extends BaseQuestion {
    isCorrect() {
        this.solved = false;
        return this.solved;
    }
}

export class Sequence extends BaseQuestion {
    constructor(
        text: string,
        explanation: string,
        hint: string,
        answers: Array<Answer>,
        options: Config
    ) {
        // always enable shuffling for sequence questions
        options.shuffleAnswers = true;
        super(text, explanation, hint, answers, 'Sequence', options);
    }

    isCorrect() {
        // extract answer ids from answers
        let trueAnswerIds = this.answers.map((answer) => answer.id);
        this.solved = isEqual(trueAnswerIds.sort(), this.selected);
        return this.solved;
    }
}
//Create a FreeResponse class that extends BaseQuestion
class FreeResponse extends BaseQuestion {
    constructor(
        text: string,
        explanation: string,
        hint: string,
        answers: Array<Answer>,
        options: Config
    ) {
        super(text, explanation, hint, answers, 'FreeResponse', options);

    }
    isCorrect() {
        let trueAnswerIds = this.answers
            .filter((answer) => answer.correct)
            .map((answer) => answer.id);
        let selectedAnswerIds = this.selected.map((i) => this.answers[i].id);
        this.solved = isEqual(trueAnswerIds.sort(), selectedAnswerIds.sort());
        return this.solved;
    }
}


class Choice extends BaseQuestion {
    isCorrect() {
        let trueAnswerIds = this.answers
            .filter((answer) => answer.correct)
            .map((answer) => answer.id);
        let selectedAnswerIds = this.selected.map((i) => this.answers[i].id);
        this.solved = isEqual(trueAnswerIds.sort(), selectedAnswerIds.sort());
        return this.solved;
    }
}

export class MultipleChoice extends Choice {
    constructor(
        text: string,
        explanation: string,
        hint: string,
        answers: Array<Answer>,
        options: Config
    ) {
        super(text, explanation, hint, answers, 'MultipleChoice', options);
    }
}

export class SingleChoice extends Choice {
    constructor(
        text: string,
        explanation: string,
        hint: string,
        answers: Array<Answer>,
        options: Config
    ) {
        super(text, explanation, hint, answers, 'SingleChoice', options);
        let nCorrect = this.answers.filter((answer) => answer.correct).length;
        if (nCorrect > 1) {
            throw 'Single Choice questions can not have more than one correct answer.';
        }
    }
}

export class Answer {
    html: string;
    correct: boolean;
    id: number;
    comment: string;

    constructor(id: number, html: string, correct: boolean, comment: string) {
        this.html = html;
        this.correct = correct;
        this.id = id;
        this.comment = comment;
        autoBind(this);
    }
}

export class Quiz {
    questions: Array<BaseQuestion>;
    active: Writable<BaseQuestion>;
    index: Writable<number>;
    config: Config;
    onLast: Writable<boolean>;
    onResults: Writable<boolean>;
    onFirst: Writable<boolean>;
    isEvaluated: Writable<boolean>;
    allVisited: Writable<boolean>;

    constructor(questions: Array<BaseQuestion>, config: Config) {
        this.index = writable(0);
        this.questions = questions;
        this.config = config;
        if (this.config.shuffleQuestions) {
            this.questions = shuffle(this.questions, this.config.nQuestions);
        }
        if (this.questions.length == 0) {
            throw 'No questions for quiz provided';
        }
        // setup first question
        this.active = writable(this.questions[0]);
        this.questions[0].visited = true;
        this.onLast = writable(this.questions.length == 1);
        this.onResults = writable(false);
        this.onFirst = writable(true);
        this.allVisited = writable(this.questions.length == 1);
        this.isEvaluated = writable(false);
        autoBind(this);
    }

    private setActive() {
        let idx = get(this.index);
        this.active.update((act) => this.questions[idx]);
        this.questions[idx].visited = true;
    }

    private checkAllVisited(): boolean {
        for (let question of this.questions) {
            if (!question.visited) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    jump(index: number): boolean {
        if (index <= this.questions.length - 1 && index >= 0) {
            // on a question
            this.index.set(index);
            this.setActive();
            this.allVisited.set(this.checkAllVisited());
            this.onResults.set(false);
            this.onLast.set(index == this.questions.length - 1);
            this.onFirst.set(index == 0);
            return true;
        } else if (index == this.questions.length) {
            // on results page
            this.onResults.set(true);
            this.onLast.set(false);
            this.index.set(index);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    next(): boolean {
        return this.jump(get(this.index) + 1);
    }

    previous(): boolean {
        return this.jump(get(this.index) - 1);
    }

    reset(): Boolean {
        this.onLast.set(false);
        this.onResults.set(false);
        this.allVisited.set(false);
        this.isEvaluated.set(false);

        this.questions.forEach((q) => q.reset());
        return this.jump(0);
    }

    evaluate(): number {
        var points = 0;
        for (var q of this.questions) {
            if (q.isCorrect()) {
                points += 1;
            }
        }
        this.isEvaluated.set(true);
        return points;
    }
}
//Export the FreeResponse class
export { FreeResponse };
```

parser.ts:

```
import DOMPurify from 'dompurify';
import stripIndent from 'strip-indent';
import {
    Quiz,
    BaseQuestion,
    MultipleChoice,
    SingleChoice,
    FreeResponse,
    Sequence,
    Answer,
    QuestionType,
} from './quiz';
import { Config, mergeAttributes } from './config';
import marked from './customizedMarked';

function parseQuizdown(rawQuizdown: string, globalConfig: Config): Quiz {
    let tokens = tokenize(rawQuizdown);
    // globalConfig < quizConfig < questionConfig
    let quizConfig = new Config(globalConfig);

    if (hasQuizOptions(tokens)) {
        quizConfig = parseOptions(tokens, quizConfig);
    }
    let firstHeadingIdx = findFirstHeadingIdx(tokens);
    let questions = extractQuestions(tokens.slice(firstHeadingIdx), quizConfig);
    return new Quiz(questions, quizConfig);
}

function tokenize(rawQuizdown: string): marked.TokensList {
    return marked.lexer(htmlDecode(stripIndent(rawQuizdown)));
}

function hasQuizOptions(tokens: marked.TokensList) {
    // type definition does not allow custom token types
    // @ts-ignore
    let optionsIdx = tokens.findIndex((token) => token['type'] == 'options');
    let headingIdx = tokens.findIndex((token) => token['type'] == 'heading');
    // quiz options appear at the top before the first heading
    return optionsIdx !== -1 && headingIdx > optionsIdx;
}

function parseOptions(tokens: marked.Token[], quizConfig: Config): Config {
    // type definition does not allow custom token types
    // @ts-ignore
    let options = tokens.find((token) => token.type == 'options');
    return mergeAttributes(quizConfig, options['data']);
}

function extractQuestions(tokens: marked.Token[], config: Config) {
    let questions: BaseQuestion[] = [];
    let nextQuestion = 0;

    while (tokens.length !== 0) {
        nextQuestion = findFirstHeadingIdx(tokens.slice(1));
        if (nextQuestion === -1) {
            // no next question on last question
            nextQuestion = tokens.length;
        }
        let question = parseQuestion(
            tokens.splice(0, nextQuestion + 1),
            config
        );
        questions.push(question);
    }
    return questions;
}

function parseQuestion(tokens: marked.Token[], config: Config): BaseQuestion {
    let explanation = parseExplanation(tokens);
    let hint = parseHint(tokens);
    let heading = parseHeading(tokens);
    let answers = parseAnswers(tokens);
    let questionType = determineQuestionType(tokens);
    let questionConfig = new Config(config);
    const args = [heading, explanation, hint, answers, questionConfig] as const;
    switch (questionType) {
        case 'SingleChoice':
            return new SingleChoice(...args);
        case 'MultipleChoice':
            return new MultipleChoice(...args);
        case 'Sequence':
            return new Sequence(...args);
        case 'FreeResponse':
            return new FreeResponse(...args);
    }
}

function findFirstHeadingIdx(tokens: marked.Token[]): number {
    return tokens.findIndex((token) => token['type'] == 'heading');
}

function parseHint(tokens: marked.Token[]): string {
    let blockquotes = tokens.filter((token) => token['type'] == 'blockquote');
    return parseTokens(blockquotes);
}

function parseExplanation(tokens: marked.Token[]): string {
    let explanations = tokens.filter(
        (token) => token['type'] == 'paragraph' || token['type'] == 'code'
    );
    return parseTokens(explanations);
}

function parseHeading(tokens: marked.Token[]): string {
    let headings = tokens.filter((token) => token['type'] == 'heading');
    return parseTokens(headings);
}

function parseAnswers(tokens: marked.Token[]): Array<Answer> {
    let list = tokens.find(
        (token) => token.type == 'list'
    ) as marked.Tokens.List;
    let answers: Array<Answer> = [];
    list.items.forEach(function (item, i) {
        let answer = parseAnswer(item);
        answers.push(
            new Answer(i, answer['text'], item['checked'], answer['comment'])
        );
    });
    return answers;
}

function parseAnswer(item: marked.Tokens.ListItem) {
    let comments = item['tokens'].filter((token) => token.type == 'blockquote');
    let texts = item['tokens'].filter((token) => token.type != 'blockquote');
    return { text: parseTokens(texts), comment: parseTokens(comments) };
}

//Modify this function to check for FreeResponse
function determineQuestionType(tokens: marked.Token[]): QuestionType {
    let list = tokens.find(
        (token) => token.type == 'list'
    ) as marked.Tokens.List;
    if (list.ordered) {
        if (list.items[0].task) {
            return 'SingleChoice';
        } else {
            return 'Sequence';
        }
    } else {
        return 'MultipleChoice';
    }
}

function parseTokens(tokens: marked.Token[]): string {
    return DOMPurify.sanitize(marked.parser(tokens as marked.TokensList));
}

function htmlDecode(text: string) {
    return text
        .replace(/&lt;/g, '<')
        .replace(/&gt;/g, '>')
        .replace(/&amp;/g, '&');
}

export default parseQuizdown;
```

App.svelte:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import type { Quiz } from './quiz';
    import ProgressBar from './components/ProgressBar.svelte';
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import registerLanguages from './languages/i18n';
    import Card from './components/Card.svelte';
    import Credits from './components/Credits.svelte';
    import SmoothResize from './components/SmoothResize.svelte';
    import QuestionView from './components/QuestionView.svelte';
    import Row from './components/Row.svelte';
    import Button from './components/Button.svelte';
    import { _ } from 'svelte-i18n';
    import ResultsView from './components/ResultsView.svelte';
    // import { Linear, CheckFirst } from './progressModes.js';
    import Animated from './components/Animated.svelte';
    import registerIcons from './registerIcons.js';
    import Icon from './components/Icon.svelte';
    import Hint from './components/Hint.svelte';
    import { fly } from 'svelte/transition';
    import Container from './components/Container.svelte';
    import Loading from './components/Loading.svelte';
    // import Modal from './components/Modal.svelte';

    export let quiz: Quiz;
    // https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/4079
    $: question = quiz.active;
    $: showHint = $question.showHint;
    $: index = quiz.index;
    $: onLast = quiz.onLast;
    $: onFirst = quiz.onFirst;
    $: onResults = quiz.onResults;
    $: isEvaluated = quiz.isEvaluated;
    $: allVisited = quiz.allVisited;

    //let game = new Linear(quiz);

    registerLanguages(quiz.config.locale);
    registerIcons();

    let node: HTMLElement;
    let minHeight = 150;
    let reloaded = false;
    // let showModal = false;

    // set global options
    onMount(async () => {
        let primaryColor: string = quiz.config.primaryColor;
        let secondaryColor: string = quiz.config.secondaryColor;
        let textColor: string = quiz.config.textColor;

        node.style.setProperty('--quizdown-color-primary', primaryColor);
        node.style.setProperty('--quizdown-color-secondary', secondaryColor);
        node.style.setProperty('--quizdown-color-text', textColor);
        node.style.minHeight = `${minHeight}px`;
    });
</script>

<div class="quizdown-content" bind:this="{node}">
    <Card>
        <ProgressBar value="{$index}" max="{quiz.questions.length - 1}" />
        <Loading update="{reloaded}" ms="{800}" minHeight="{minHeight}">
            <Container>
                <SmoothResize minHeight="{minHeight}">
                    <Animated update="{$index}">
                        {#if $onResults}
                            <ResultsView quiz="{quiz}" />
                        {:else}
                            <QuestionView
                                question="{$question}"
                                n="{$index + 1}"
                            />
                            <Hint hint="{$question.hint}" show="{$showHint}" />
                        {/if}
                    </Animated>
                </SmoothResize>

                <!-- <Modal show="{showModal}">Are you sure?</Modal> -->

                <Row>
                    <Button
                        slot="left"
                        title="{$_('hint')}"
                        disabled="{!$question.hint || $showHint || $onResults}"
                        buttonAction="{$question.enableHint}"
                        ><Icon name="lightbulb" solid="{false}" /></Button
                    >
                    <svelte:fragment slot="center">
                        <Button
                            title="{$_('previous')}"
                            disabled="{$onFirst || $onResults || $isEvaluated}"
                            buttonAction="{quiz.previous}"
                            ><Icon name="arrow-left" size="lg" /></Button
                        >

                        <Button
                            disabled="{$onLast || $onResults || $isEvaluated}"
                            buttonAction="{quiz.next}"
                            title="{$_('next')}"
                            ><Icon name="arrow-right" size="lg" /></Button
                        >

                        {#if $onLast || $allVisited}
                            <div in:fly="{{ x: 200, duration: 500 }}">
                                <Button
                                    disabled="{!($onLast || $allVisited) ||
                                        $onResults}"
                                    title="{$_('evaluate')}"
                                    buttonAction="{() =>
                                        quiz.jump(quiz.questions.length)}"
                                    ><Icon
                                        name="check-double"
                                        size="lg"
                                    /></Button
                                >
                            </div>
                        {/if}
                    </svelte:fragment>

                    <Button
                        slot="right"
                        title="{$_('reset')}"
                        buttonAction="{() => {
                            reloaded = !reloaded;
                            quiz.reset();
                        }}"><Icon name="redo" /></Button
                    >
                </Row>

                <Credits />
            </Container>
        </Loading>
    </Card>
</div>

<!-- global styles applied to all elements in the app -->
<style type="text/scss" global>
    @import 'highlight.js/styles/github';
    @import 'katex/dist/katex';
    @import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles';

    img {
        max-height: 400px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }

    code {
        padding: 0 0.4rem;
        font-size: 85%;
        color: #333;
        white-space: pre-wrap;
        border-radius: 4px;
        padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
        background-color: #f8f8f8;
        font-family: Consolas, Monaco, monospace;
    }

    a {
        color: var(--quizdown-color-primary);
    }

    .quizdown-content {
        padding: 1rem;
        max-width: 900px;
        margin: auto;
    }
</style>
```

Any assistance in working towards my feature update for Quizdown.